# Is there a way to get the value_type from a template var which is function parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a virtual method, and one of its parameter a `std::vector`. Inside, I use `std::unordered_set` with the same `value_type` of the `std::vector`.

But, I may change the `value_type` of the `std::vector`, and I don't want to change each time the type inside the code. To better understand what I am saying (English is not my native language), see the code below please.

```cpp
run(std::vector<Node> &data) {
    std::unordered_set<Node> var;
}
```

And what I expect is a thing like this :

```cpp
run(std::vector<Node> &data) {
    std::unordered_set<data::value_type> var;
}
```

And, of course, it doesn't work. Thank you in advance.

EDIT : Thank you very much for the answers, and especially this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56563062/11203604

The answers with the function template, it is impossible : it is an overloaded function (virtual). As for the class template, for technical reason in my future work, I can not make it template as it could be a public class.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe `template`? `template <typename T> run(std::vector<T> &data) {
    std::unordered_set<T> var;`
}

Comment: You get it through the class, as in `std::vector<Node>::value_type`. Which in this case is kind of redundant, but makes much more sense if the container type was a template argument (as in `template<typename C> void run(C& data) { std::unordered_set<C::value_type> var; ... }`).

Comment: `template<typename T = Node> void run(std::vector<T>& data) { std::unordred_set< std::vector<T>::value_type > var;  ...}` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `decltype` to get the type of `data` and then apply `::value_type` to that.  That would give you

```
std::unordered_set<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(data)>::value_type> var;
```

As pointed out be [Evg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625187/evg) in the comments the `std::remove_reference_t` is needed since `data` is a reference and you can't apply the scope resolution operator to a reference type.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps just make a template function?

```
template <typename T>
void run(std::vector<T>&)
{
    std::unordered_set<T> set;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply generalise your function to be a `template` over the container type

```
template<typename Container>
void run(Container const&data) const
{
    std::unordered_set<typename Container::value_type> set;
    for(auto const& x : data) {
        /* do something clever with the datum x */
    }
}
```

such that it will work with any container type that supports `value_type`.

However, traditionally the generic way in C++ is to use iterators:

```
template<typename Iter>
void run(Iter begin, Iter end) const
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;
    std::unordered_set<value_type> set;
    for(; begin != end; ++begin) {
        const value_type&x = *begin;
        /* do something clever with the datum x */
    }
}
```